# Composer install Yii2 PHP

Tags: php, mysql, npm, yii2, composer-php

I'm trying to install the composer on Local Host. It is showing errors like:

[image]

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

                                                                                
  [Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Exception\InvalidCreateRepositoryException]         
  The "repository.url" parameter of "zrender.js" npm asset package must be present for create a VCS Repository
  If the config comes from the NPM Registry, override the config with a custom Asset VCS Repository
                                                                                

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["sso", "auth","yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "unti1x/yii2-eveonline-sso": "*",
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "^2.4",
        "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "~2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "@dev",
        "newerton/yii2-fancybox": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
        "wanfeiyy/dd": "^1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-label-inplace": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "^1.6",
        "kartik-v/yii2-password": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-dynagrid": "^1.4.5",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.0@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-sortable-input": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "~2.1.0",
        "avalara/avatax": "*",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^5.1",
        "caijq4ever/yii2-urlalias": "dev-master",
        "m35/thecsv": "^1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "dev-master",
        "yiisoft/yii2-queue": "dev-master",
        "maddoger/yii2-jquery-autocomplete": "*",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.4",
        "daixianceng/yii2-echarts": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "yii2assets/yii2-pdfjs": "dev-master",
        "vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension": "0.1.0",
        "wadeshuler/yii2-sendgrid": "^1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-httpclient": "^2.0",
        "workerman/phpsocket.io": "^1.1",
        "lorance-fd/yii2-excel": "dev-master",
        "desarrolla2/cache": "^2.0.0",
        "jasny/validation-result": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.1.0",
        "jasny/php-code-quality": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset":{
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "common/helper/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Jasny\\SSO\\": "src/"
        }
    }
    
}
```

I run the command is `Composer install`. it is unable to install it.

Comment: Include your `composer.json` and show what command you run

Comment: Please check it now sir,

Comment: There is no such npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zrender.js returns 404

Comment: The zrender package is in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zrender

Comment: Sounds like at least one of your packages includes the npm zrender package by using and is missing the repository URL. I would remove some of the packages which might require js packages (mostly UI packages) consecutively and observe when the error is not longer thrown. So you can identify the error causing package and inspect it on packagist.